# Pandas - Shift column values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

Name_A ¦  id1 ¦ date 1 ¦ 1

Name_A ¦  id1 ¦ date 2 ¦ 0

Name_A ¦  id1 ¦ date 3 ¦ 1

Name_A ¦  id1 ¦ date 4 ¦ 1

Name_A ¦  id1 ¦ date 5 ¦ 1

Name_B ¦  id2 ¦ date 6 ¦ 0

Name_B ¦  id2 ¦ date 7 ¦ 1

Name_B ¦  id2 ¦ date 8 ¦ 1

...

And I would like to get this:

Name_A ¦ date1 ¦ 0

Name_A ¦ date2 ¦ 1

Name_A ¦ date3 ¦ 1

Name_A ¦ date4 ¦ 1

Name_A ¦ date5 ¦ NaN

Name_B ¦ date6 ¦ 1

Name_B ¦ date7 ¦ 1

Name_B ¦ date8 ¦ NaN

...

I would like to shift the values on the column for a specific name group.

Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a dictionary, And when you call it back, skip id field.

```
dictionary_from_data_frame = {"NameA":["NameA","id1", "date 2", 0]}
```

When you call it back,

```
_val = dictionary_from_data_frame["NameA"]

_val[0]|_val[2]|_val[3]
```

Hope you the idea.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shift the values in the last column then you can select the column using iloc, and then set it to a re-ordering of itself. For example:

df.iloc[:,2] = [df.iloc[:,2][i] for i in [2,0,1]]

This selects the second column, and then reorders it so that the third row entry is now first, then the old first row entry is now second etc.